# Does somebody know why WorldWind opens up this way?

Tags: java, eclipse, worldwind

As mentioned in the question, my WorldWind application renders the globe and all my window elements in a bizarre manner. It seems to be anchored in the bottom left corner. I attach an image as an example. I mention that I am running it on a laptop with Windows 11 using Eclipse and that the app works just fine on my PC with Windows 10. The thing is I need this program to be on my laptop... Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
[WorldWindApp.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o0Ra.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For anyone having this issue, you can find the resolve on GitHub/WorldWind at this link: https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WorldWindJava/issues/195